PHP Artisan Migration - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
I'm having a problem running 'php artisan migrate' command, this is the error I got
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'e-commerce-web-proto' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:829
    825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    826▕                 );
    827▕             }
    828▕
  ➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
    830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    831▕             );
    832▕         }
    833▕     }

I already changed the Database name to match the one I use, also run the php artisan config:cache. any thing else i need to do?
here is my env. file
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=e-commerce-web-proto
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

and here is my database config
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),


Have you tried running php artisan optimize:clear?  Running php artisan config:cache caches your configurations. Also check your database configuration details.

It seems your mysql does not have a password, can you log in to MySQL by mysql -u root?

I solved it, it seems the problem is the Password, thanks @parastoo for the inspiration. i just need to reset the password to mysql and the command worked. hopes this help for others

mysql -u root -p

verify your teminal can login.

next 

php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear


'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],

 check MySQL service is running
 sudo service mysql status
 
 sudo service mysql start

 now try 
 php artisan migrate

